# HystrixCommand interface in hystrix-javanica annotation is missing ThreadPoolProperties

Tags: java, aspectj, netflix, hystrix

I am trying to use hystrix-javanica for AspectJ annotations for HystrixCommand.
I am able to configure the command properties as follows:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "myCommand",
    groupKey = "myServiceImpl",
    threadPoolKey = "myThreadPoolKey",
    fallbackMethod = "getFallback",
    commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value =       "20000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "1000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "20000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage", value = "20000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "20000"),
    }
    )
    )
```

but I don't see the option to configure threadpool properties.
I checked the interface and it does not have it: [github link](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/908a9a061faf24aab5bf7920b19ea970f4f32620/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/annotation/HystrixCommand.java)
Is there any other way to specify it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. Yes, I missed this properties. Thread pool properties added to @HystrixCommand. Just update version of hystrix in your project.